# Inverse Search in Kile with Miktex in Windows10?

Tags: editors, kile

I am trying the editor Kile with Miktex in Windows10. It is pretty awesome. Only one thing, so far, that a user seems unable to do an inverse search, in the sense that if she clicks somewhere in the preview then Kile will take her to the corresponding location in the source file. Texstudio perfectly allows this inverse search to take place.

I am asking for a help in setting up manually the inverse searching.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, @KJO, thanks. I am not sure I follow the info. Could you please leave a specific answer? Thanks.

Comment: @KJO, I see. I guess it is the same version. Did not pay much attention to that. I found it quite impressive. It ran so well that it does not look like only testing version. Are you aware of any real ``problems" with the testing version? Thanks...

Comment: Ok I have reset my installation and tested 32bit Kile with built in Okular is working as well as can be expected on 64bit win 10. So either version should work in your setup without any changes. Sequence is open .tex ensure it is compiled and showing in viewer then shift left click will jump to tex at nearest suitable point (which may not be exactly where you would expect)

Comment: @KJO, Thanks so much! It worked pretty awesome. It turns out it is me that ignored the ``shift"! I did not even change any setting.

Comment: @KJO, If you don't mind, just a possibly quick question: I found that in an article documentclass, the direct search seems working fine except the title and author area.

Comment: I am going to remove early comments as misleading you can answer what you found the correct command was

Comment: I don't think class as such is the problem synctex works by block (not line as one would expect) so a title block can be problematic depending on how constructed

Comment: @KJO, Thanks! Please feel free to post the answer ("shift + left click"). I already got what I was after!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the latest Kile 3 on windows it includes a dedicated copy of Okular PDF viewer
This allows for forward and inverse search out of the box. There is no need for other viewers. However it is possible to add other external viewers if desired.

For forward search the TeX file must be compiled using synctex (the default for PdfLaTeX)
and ViewPDF activated. Selecting a piece of the tex file (here the \maketitle) a blue highlight line will temporarily appear in the PDF window, in this example it is shown under the date.

[image]

In order to jump back from the PDF window to the relevant block of TeX, Okular **requires** that **browse** (not zoom etc.) is active and then a **SHIFT & Left Click** will move the tex cursor to the nearest relevant point. Note in this case a selection above the date has NOT gone back to \maketitle (nor above it) nor has it gone where the blue line is after abstract but is positioned **after** \maketitle and before \begin{abstract}

[image]